# "C#" - A consulta parametrizada @imagem bi espera o parametro @imagem que não foi fornecido!

Tags: c#

Galera, estou criando um sistema de caixa e na parte de alterar o cadastro o programa dá o seguinte erro "A consulta parametrizada @imagem bi espera o parametro @imagem que não foi fornecido!". Engraçado é que quando eu coloco uma nova foto, funciona normalmente! Já quando eu altero só o nome, aparece este erro!

Código abaixo!

```
//O código abaixo é referente ao botão "Carregar Foto".

    int novaFoto;
    byte [] foto;
    Bitmap bmp;

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string caminho = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            bmp = new Bitmap(caminho);

            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;

            novaFoto += 1;

        }

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    //O código abaixo é referente ao botão "Alterar Cadastro".


    string nomeBanco;


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (novaFoto != 0)

        { 
            MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();

            bmp.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Bmp);

            foto = memory.ToArray();
        }

        novaFoto = 0;



        SqlCommand cad = new SqlCommand("update Produto set nome = @nome, codigo = @codigo, quant = @quant, preco = @preco, imagem = @imagem, fornecedor = @fornecedor where (nome = '"+nomeBanco+"')", con);

        SqlParameter nome = new SqlParameter("@nome", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        SqlParameter codigo = new SqlParameter("@codigo", SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter quant = new SqlParameter("@quant", SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter preco = new SqlParameter("@preco", SqlDbType.Float);
        SqlParameter imagem = new SqlParameter("@imagem", SqlDbType.Binary);
        SqlParameter fornecedor = new SqlParameter("@fornecedor", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        //AQUIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII antes tava foto;
        nome.Value = textBox1.Text;
        codigo.Value = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        fornecedor.Value = textBox3.Text;
        preco.Value = float.Parse(textBox4.Text);
        quant.Value = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
        imagem.Value = foto;


        cad.Parameters.Add(nome);
        cad.Parameters.Add(codigo);
        cad.Parameters.Add(quant);
        cad.Parameters.Add(preco);
        cad.Parameters.Add(imagem);
        cad.Parameters.Add(fornecedor);





        try
        {


            con.Open();
            cad.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("alterado com sucesso!");
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox4.Clear();
            textBox5.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();

        }

        catch (Exception E)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(E.Message);

        }

        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            pesquisar();
        }



    }

    private void textBox6_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        pesquisar();
    }
```

Comment: ignorando completamente os problemas do código, o erro que está sendo exibido é porque você só preenche a variável `foto` quando `novafoto != 0` (você poderia simplesmente usar um bool aqui), quando é =0, a variável não é atribuída e não tem valor no parâmetro. Ainda assim, se passar `null`, capaz de remover a foto do banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente desta forma:

```
bool novaFoto = false;
byte [] foto;
Bitmap bmp;

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        bmp = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);

        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        novaFoto = true;
    }
}

string nomeBanco;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Sql = "UPDATE Produto SET nome = @nome, codigo = @codigo, quant = @quant, preco = @preco, fornecedor = @fornecedor";
    string Where = $" WHERE nome = '{nomeBanco}'";

    if (novaFoto)
    { 
        MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();

        bmp.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        foto = memory.ToArray();

        Sql += ", imagem = @imagem";
    }

    SqlCommand cad = new SqlCommand(Sql + Where, con);

    cad.Parameters.Add("@nome", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
    cad.Parameters.Add("@codigo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    cad.Parameters.Add("@quant", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
    cad.Parameters.Add("@preco", SqlDbType.Float).Value = float.Parse(textBox4.Text);
    cad.Parameters.Add("@fornecedor", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;

    if (novaFoto)
        cad.Parameters.Add("@imagem", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = foto;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cad.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("alterado com sucesso!");

        pictureBox1.Image = null;

        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox4.Clear();
        textBox5.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();

        novaFoto = false;
    }

    catch (Exception E)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(E.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        pesquisar();
    }
}
```

Otimizei um pouco o seu código, mas a diferença mais importante é mesmo a construção da *query* SQL com ou sem o parâmetro da imagem, dependendo se está preenchida ou não.